# Choc pudding, cook & serve hasn't thickened

Tags: pudding

I cooked it for 30 min over medium high heat, stirring frequently. I used 2% milk. It didn't thicken completely, but eventually I removed it from heat, thinking it would thicken in the fridge.  It hasn't. Can I bake it in the oven for a few minutes?

Comment: Is this pudding from scratch, or boxed pudding, like [Jello](http://www.amazon.com/Jell-O-Instant-Pudding-Filling-3-4-Ounce/dp/B00JD9XUEW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1423238733&sr=8-1&keywords=jello+pudding)?

Comment: If the pudding was from scratch, please post a recipe. Whether it was from a box or from scratch, did it ever come to a boil? How confident are you that you measured properly?

Comment: Also, do you have cornstarch on hand?